# jquery ui switching from tab view to one view works fine with single tab widget but not when tab is subtab of another tab widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

jquery ui switching from  tab view to one view works fine with single tab widget but not when tab widget is child of another tab widget.  The goal is keep the parent tabs intact, but have a button (show child tabs or show child one view) that controls the viewing of child info.
I have it working but had to also change the parent tabs to non tabs.  See in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/remy/GhpqB/10/

Does anyone know how to keep the parent tabs intact but allow the child tabs to be able switch from tabbed view to one page view?

Thanks,

Frankie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('destroy')
```

to destroy the tab functionality, and then re-initialise them in the show tabs function.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhpqB/12/)

Comment: Excellent solution. Many thanks.. Fiddle makes asking/showing/etc lots easier.